# How to create Apex test code for deleting individual email responses?

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, unit-test

We have a lot of Individual Email Response records. We'd like an easy way to delete them. I've created a Visualforce Page with Apex code to back it. Now I need a test class. If I try to create a IER (API name = et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c), I get a message saying that the IER needs a Send Definition. Send Definition has API name of et4ae5__SendDefinition__c. If I try to create a Send Definition, I get the following error message:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: >CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, et4ae5.updateBURecord: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: >System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject (System Code): []

Here is the code that causes the error

```
et4ae5__SendDefinition__c sd = new et4ae5__SendDefinition__c();
sd.et4ae5__DateSent__c = DateTime.now();
sd.et4ae5__SendStatus__c = 'Completed';
sd.et4ae5__FromEmail__c = 'info@ceres.org';
sd.et4ae5__FromName__c = 'Some Guy, A title';
sd.et4ae5__EmailName__c = 'The Test Email';
//sd.et4ae5__Campaign__c = cmp.Id;
insert sd;
```

UpdateBURecord is a managed trigger from Marketing Cloud. The code is hidden. Does anyone know how to create a valid Send Definition via Apex code? What have I missed.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to create a Business Unit (`et4ae5__Business_Unit__c`), for which the only required fields should be Name (`Name`), Business Unit Id (`et4ae5__Business_Unit_ID__c`), and Enabled (`et4ae5__Enabled__c`). From there, create a `et4ae5__SendDefinition__c` that includes `et4ae5__Business_Unit__c`.

```
et4ae5__Business_Unit__c bu = new et4ae5__Business_Unit__c(
  Name='Test', 
  et4ae5__Business_Unit_ID__c = '12345',
  et4ae5__Enabled__c = true
);
insert bu;
et4ae5__SendDefinition__c sd = new et4ae5__SendDefinition__c();
sd.et4ae5__Business_Unit__c = bu.Id;
sd.et4ae5__DateSent__c = DateTime.now();
sd.et4ae5__SendStatus__c = 'Completed';
sd.et4ae5__FromEmail__c = 'info@ceres.org';
sd.et4ae5__FromName__c = 'Some Guy, A title';
sd.et4ae5__EmailName__c = 'The Test Email';
//sd.et4ae5__Campaign__c = cmp.Id;
insert sd;
```

Even though we can't see the code, the actual problem is obvious. We're given that "no SOQL rows are returned", so we know it's a query, and the `updateBURecord` error strongly suggests we were trying to update a Business Unit, which is almost universally abbreviated as BU in the MC material.